# Widgets change places when running from design tab

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am building a visual studio application and have designed it using visual studio windows form. I am using the siticone library for the GUI but when i lay widgets out on the designer and then run the application all the widgets move. The buttons do not but the labs on them do. Also i have added a user control page that moves aswell. Please Help.

Cheers.enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Winform Font style and size match with all child controls including all Siticone controls.

Verify that you have anchored your controls accordingly on your form or panel control.